# Setting state of a created but not mounted React component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component I'm creating as a local variable. I'd like to tweak its state before attaching it to the DOM. A super-simplified version of the code looks like this:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {foo: 2};
    }
    render() {
        return <p>{this.state.foo}</p>;
    }
}


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let elem = <Demo/>;
        elem.setState({foo:4});
     }
 }
```

(The real code has a point, but I'm posting the simplified test case so you don't have to read long irrelevancies)

I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: elem.setState is not a function
```

What does this error mean?  I'm checked that element is an instance of Demo.

Is there a way to set the state at this time?

ETA: I know what `props` is.  I really want to modify the element *after* creating it.

Comment: `setState` is not accessible outside of the component itself

Comment: Would it make sense in your solution to use a prop to set the initial state?

Comment: incorrect at all

Answer (score -1):

You can't setstate like this. If you want to manipulate state in the child component you have to add props to do that.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Demo extends Component {
  state = {
    foo: this.props.foo || 0
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    console.log(prevState.foo, this.props.foo);

    if (prevState.foo !== this.props.foo) {
      this.setState({ foo: this.props.foo });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <button {...this.props}>{this.state.foo}</button>;
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };
  clickMe = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
  };
  render() {
    return <Demo onClick={() => this.clickMe()} foo={this.state.count} />;
  }
}
```

Here is working example https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-rhodes-redk7